# Using OR in the WHEN conditions in DROOLS

Tags: drools

I have a problem with a rule in Drools.

In a drl file i have a rule:

```
rule ""               
 when
        $g: class1( $tm: list1 )
        $p: class2() from $tm
    $ph: class3(isEnd==false,  $s: steps) from $p.list2  
    $st: Step(isEnd==false ) from $s        

  then
      ----
 end
```

I want a OR with the 3th and 4th conditions.

How can i do it?

Comment: You can't make the 4th conditional expression ("Step") depend on something from the 3rd conditional expression and ask for an OR, which should match if the 3rd CE does NOT match: but then you don't have `$s` from which to construct the 4th CE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I haven't tested it:

```
rule "xxx"               
when
    $g: class1( $tm: list1 )
    $p: class2() from $tm
    ( class3(isEnd==false ) from $p.list2
       or
     ( $ph: class3(isEnd==true ) from $p.list2
       and
       Step(isEnd==false ) from $ph.getSteps() )
    )
then
  ----
end
```

Comment: I tried it but it still not working. I have this error:

"No viable alternative at input 'class3' in rule"

For me the problem is the "from" clause in the condition, because without it in other code works...

Comment: Which "from" clause? There should be more info in the error message, a line number, perhaps. --- And: I can't reproduce this without the definitions for "class1/2/3". It's too much work to reconstruct what you *might* have.